# dynamically adjust to the unzipped folder name in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having trouble setting the correct path to the folder containing my batch file. For example, right now, I have a zipped file called "example.zip". This zip file contains 4 files within it (file1, file2, file3, file4). When a user right-clicks and extracts the 4 files, they are given the option to rename the file path and folder name. By default, the folder name gets saved as "example". In my batch script, I can find and move the files great if they don't change the folder name. But if they change the folder name path to C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\"notexample" then it screws up the batch file.

I'm wondering how to grab the folder path after the user has extracted the the zip file and named it possibly something other than the default name.

My current configuration in my batch script is

for \f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s "cd:~0,2%\Users\%username%\example" 2^>nul') do set filepath=%%F

This is just searching for any folder that matches "example" in the Users\Downloads directory and grabs the file path. You can see the problem if the user renames the folder "notexample". My batch script yells "folder not found"

Thanks

Comment: Is the batch file inside the directory?

Comment: yes, sorry. The batch file is inside the example.zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a batch file's location is quite simple, use the `%~dp0` variable:

```
echo %~dp0
```

returns the batch file's folder.

That means you could simply use this:

```
set "filepath=%~dp0"
```

This won't require the `for` loop.

Comment: awesome, did not anticipate it being that simple.

Comment: @bm07 There are lots of "hidden" features in batch. These kinds of variables are, for example, "documented" in the help for `for`. Weird, but true.

Comment: These argument references like `%0`, `%1` are documented in the help of `call /?`...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, but `d, p, n, x, f`... are documented in `for`.